# Eclipse not responding, stuck at Initializing Java Tooling 30%

Tags: java, eclipse

My Eclipse stuck at Initializing Java Tooling 30% after startup. I can't do anything on it. The mouse pointer is showing busy.

From the eclipse error log, I see "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" but I don't think it's due to limited memory. I tried given it 4GB memory but that did not help. This is not a one-time issue, it happens every time I start the Eclipse.

My workspace only has one Java project.

I'm using Eclipse Oxygen, before I was using Eclipse Mars2, both have the same issue. OS is macOS Sierra version 10.12.6.

My current eclipse.ini:

```
$ cat .//Contents/Eclipse/eclipse.ini
-startup
../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.library
../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.500.v20170531-1133
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-showsplash
org.eclipse.epp.package.common
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms1024m
-Xmx2048m
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
```

Below is a piece of eclipse error log(workspace/.metadata/.log), I uploaded the whole log to https://github.com/gangkui2008/eclipse/blob/master/.log.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2017-09-07 20:31:24.280
!MESSAGE Unable to create class 'org.eclipse.ui.internal.LegacyTrim' from bundle '818'
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.getTrimManager()Lorg/eclipse/ui/internal/layout/ITrimManager;
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ToolControlRenderer.createWidget(ToolControlRenderer.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:666)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:772)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:743)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:737)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:721)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.TrimBarRenderer.processContents(TrimBarRenderer.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:680)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$1.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.WBWRenderer.processContents(WBWRenderer.java:726)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:680)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:772)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:743)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:737)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:721)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1081)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1044)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:680)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.getTrimManager()Lorg/eclipse/ui/internal/layout/ITrimManager;
    at com.ibm.team.workitem.rcp.ui.internal.WorkItemRCPUIPlugin.setQuickSearchTrimVisibility(WorkItemRCPUIPlugin.java:328)
    at com.ibm.team.workitem.rcp.ui.internal.WorkItemRCPUIPlugin.setQuickSearchTrimVisibility(WorkItemRCPUIPlugin.java:344)
    at com.ibm.team.workitem.rcp.ui.internal.WorkItemRCPUIPlugin.updateQuickSearchTrimVisibility(WorkItemRCPUIPlugin.java:323)
    at com.ibm.team.workitem.rcp.ui.internal.quicksearch.SearchBarTrim.fill(SearchBarTrim.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.LegacyTrim.createWidget(LegacyTrim.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:990)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:399)
    ... 47 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2017-09-07 20:31:24.523
!MESSAGE Unable to create class 'org.eclipse.ui.internal.LegacyTrim' from bundle '818'
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.getTrimManager()Lorg/eclipse/ui/internal/layout/ITrimManager;
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ToolControlRenderer.createWidget(ToolControlRenderer.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:666)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:772)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:743)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:737)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:721)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.TrimBarRenderer.processContents(TrimBarRenderer.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:680)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$1.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.WBWRenderer.processContents(WBWRenderer.java:726)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:680)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:772)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:743)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:737)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:721)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1081)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1044)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:680)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.getTrimManager()Lorg/eclipse/ui/internal/layout/ITrimManager;
    at com.ibm.team.metronome.MetronomePlugin.setMetronomeVisible(MetronomePlugin.java:74)
    at com.ibm.team.metronome.internal.VisibilityController.updateVisibility(VisibilityController.java:53)
    at com.ibm.team.metronome.internal.MetronomeWidget.fill(MetronomeWidget.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.LegacyTrim.createWidget(LegacyTrim.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:990)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:399)
    ... 47 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2017-09-07 20:31:25.627
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.getTrimManager()Lorg/eclipse/ui/internal/layout/ITrimManager;
    at com.ibm.team.collaboration.internal.ui.trim.ChangePresenceWorkbenchTrim.updateVisibility(ChangePresenceWorkbenchTrim.java:73)
    at com.ibm.team.collaboration.internal.ui.trim.ChangePresenceWorkbenchTrim.access$0(ChangePresenceWorkbenchTrim.java:65)
    at com.ibm.team.collaboration.internal.ui.trim.ChangePresenceWorkbenchTrim$1.run(ChangePresenceWorkbenchTrim.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4033)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3700)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1044)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:680)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)

!ENTRY com.ibm.team.fulltext.common 1 800 2017-09-07 20:32:13.415
!MESSAGE Fulltext:: Server location: /Users/stone/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/com.ibm.team.fulltext.client/fulltext_index/com.ibm.team.workitem.WorkItem

!ENTRY com.ibm.team.workitem.rcp.ui 4 0 2017-09-07 20:44:57.717
!MESSAGE Exception running 'Refreshing Project Areas'
!STACK 0
com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport.ServiceMethodInvocationError: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.ibm.team.repository.transport.client.RemoteTeamService.getAppropriateException(RemoteTeamService.java:643)
    at com.ibm.team.repository.transport.client.RemoteTeamService.executeMethod(RemoteTeamService.java:518)
    at com.ibm.team.repository.transport.client.RemoteTeamService.invoke(RemoteTeamService.java:194)
    at com.ibm.team.repository.transport.client.ServiceInvocationHandler.invoke(ServiceInvocationHandler.java:43)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.fetchOrRefreshItems(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor65.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.ibm.team.repository.client.internal.ServiceInterfaceProxy.invokeServiceCall(ServiceInterfaceProxy.java:254)
    at com.ibm.team.repository.client.internal.ServiceInterfaceProxy.invoke(ServiceInterfaceProxy.java:110)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.fetchOrRefreshItems(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.team.repository.client.internal.ItemManager$4.run(ItemManager.java:1672)
    at com.ibm.team.repository.client.internal.ItemManager$4.run(ItemManager.java:1)
    at com.ibm.team.repository.client.internal.TeamRepository$3.run(TeamRepository.java:1324)
    at com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport.CancelableCaller.call(CancelableCaller.java:79)
    at com.ibm.team.repository.client.internal.TeamRepository.callCancelableService(TeamRepository.java:1319)
    at com.ibm.team.repository.client.internal.TeamPlatformObject.callCancelableService(TeamPlatformObject.java:42)
    at com.ibm.team.repository.client.internal.ItemManager.internalFetchItems(ItemManager.java:1667)
    at com.ibm.team.repository.client.internal.ItemManager.access$3(ItemManager.java:1625)
    at com.ibm.team.repository.client.internal.ItemManager$AbstractStore.retrieveItems(ItemManager.java:227)
    at com.ibm.team.repository.client.internal.ItemManager$CurrentStore.fetchItems(ItemManager.java:373)
    at com.ibm.team.repository.client.internal.ItemManager.fetchPartialItems(ItemManager.java:1132)
    at com.ibm.team.workitem.rcp.ui.internal.WorkItemRCPUIPlugin$InternalUpdaterJob.runProtected(WorkItemRCPUIPlugin.java:130)
    at com.ibm.team.foundation.client.util.FoundationJob.run(FoundationJob.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2017-09-07 20:45:09.846


!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Deferred storing of feeds".
!STACK 0
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Can someone tell me what's the problem and how to solve it? Thanks very much.

Comment: I can confirm, STS 3.9.5. Very serious problem.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem on STS 4.11.0

Answer (score -1):

Try reinstalling eclipse, usually this fixes bugs like this. It won't hurt any of your files. I don't personally use eclipse anymore because of errors like these. Consider looking over other questions for help, or use alternatives that won't yell at you for having invalid methods like IntelliJ. Hope I helped a bit.

Comment: Tried reinstalling eclipse but it did not work. Guess it's a IBM RTC plugin issue. Removed it then everything is ok now.